# Javafx how to set resolution

Tags: javafx

How can I set the optimal resolution for my project, so, the screen should be auto-sized after running the project. 
I have a gridpane, filled with images in each cell. The gridpane is wrapped in an anchorpane, which is also wrapped in an anchorpane.
The first screen with a resolution of 1920x1080 is perfect, but on another Screen with 1366x768 the elements are totally shifted. I want to have, that the resolution works for all screen well.